# Force ADODB return EOF if length of returned data equals zero

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

I have one query that returns a single element.

This record has a empty data (Length = 0, but not null).

I Want to know if is possible force the query return `EOF` if the data length equals zero.

```vb
sql="select Code from AS_Table where NumAtend = 1234 "
set rs = Con1.execute(sql)

if not rs.eof then
    Json("status") = true
else
    Json("status") = false
end if
```

I Know you can test it after the "IF", but don't want to know how to fix that (Because I already know).

My question is "if" it is possible force an `EOF` if the `len(Code)=0`

Comment: Not sure I get you but couldn't you just tell the SQL to only return data if the field `Code` length is greater then 0? `select Code from AS_Table where NumAtend = 1234 AND LEN(Code) > 0` That way you will always get `EOF` if `LEN(Code) < 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a [comment earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542961/force-adodb-return-eof-if-length-of-returned-data-equals-zero#comment36119449_23542961) but seen as though everyone has jumped on the answer wagon here goes;

```sql
SELECT Code FROM AS_Table WHERE NumAtend = 1234 AND LEN(Code) > 0
```

By adding the `LEN(Code) > 0` will cause only results with `Code` with a length greater then 0 to be returned.

In each instance you want a `ADODB.Recordset` to be returned or you will not be able to check the `Recordset.EOF` property this is because the `ADODB.Recordset` will have a `Recordset.State` of `adStateClosed` and any attempt to access it's properties will return an error (`adErrObjectClosed`).

```
 Error No.   | Description
------------------------------------------------------------------
-2146824578  | Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.
```

---

**What about using RETURN?**

The problem with `RETURN` is you will not get a resultset back so the `ADODB.Recordset` will be in the state `adStateClosed` and the same as above will apply.

---

**Useful Links**

- [State Property (ADO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675068(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Good. Transfer my conditions to SQL until I get what i want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force ADO to change its defined behaviour (unless you patch the .dll). Either add an If clause/statement to your code or a WHERE clause ("... WHERE codelength > 0") to your SQL statement.

Comment: That's pretty much what I said minus the bit about changing behaviour not sure where you are going with that.

Comment: `and LEN(Code)> 0` .. Pff.. Simple like that. Thanks.

Comment: @Lankymart That's why I upvoted your comment (which I saw after I answered). Post it as answer and will upvote it, because your WHERE clause is better than mine. The 'patch' remark is meant ironycally.

Comment: Should have just answered, I was too busy trying to see if there was a duplicate of this question, seemed quite and obvious one (at first took me a few attempts to understand what OP was asking).

Answer (score 0):

To do this programatically through your application, you could filter your result set.

```
sql="select Code from AS_Table where NumAtend = 1234 "
set rs = Con1.execute(sql)
rs.filter = "status <> ''"

if not rs.eof then
    Json("status") = true
else
    Json("status") = false
end if
```

This will give you rs.EOF if the "status" field is empty